# Eventmachine system command

Tags: ruby, command, system, eventmachine

I am using [Eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine)

Need run a command system on the server and send the output of terminal to the client in real time.

Try with :

**Server**

```
EM.run{
       EM.system('#command'){ |output| 
       send_data output 
                            }
      }
```

**Client**

```
def receive_data(data)
    puts data 
end
```

Works, but sends the data when the command finishes running, not in real time.

Any idea ?

Comment: This is how it is implemented right now. Pretty sure a streaming pipe implementation of `system` method will be useful.

Comment: Hi, yes, with pipen works. Thanks